# Regex to match a specific character?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need to make a Regular expression that will match the character "N" when it is alone. So far, I've come up with the expression: `"^[N]$"` which seems to work in this example. It doesn't match on the other three, just the "N".

```
public static void Main()
{
    string[] words = new string[] { "42ND", "N", "WATERING", "ANONYMOUS"};

    string pattern = @"^[N]$";

    foreach (string word in words)
    {
        if( Regex.IsMatch(word, pattern))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(word + " Is a match"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone pick out any problems with this or provide a better one? Thank you!

Edit for a little clarity: 
I'm just looking to match on the letter `"N"` and nothing more. It should not match on "NN", "NNN", or any variation and should not match on any words that contain the letter `"N"`.

Comment: because it is made to match a single "N"

Comment: `word.IndexOf("N")>=0` or `word.Contains("N")` ?

Comment: It's not clear from your question, do you *want* the other words to match?  Or are you happy that only `"N"` matches?

Comment: I just need only the `"N"` matches.

Comment: Should `"some N text"` match?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. I'm just looking for the letter `N`.

Comment: This looks like a college project, if it is I would consider totally over-engineering it: add i18n, parallelism, security, and some premature optimizations.

Comment: How about `word.Equals("N")`?

Comment: @d2jxp you closed your recent question, but here is working code for your problem. You could use reflection to avoid the constructor stuff I did in Main() as well. http://ideone.com/r3H6RS

Answer (score 4):

You could use `\b` (word boundary match) that way you could pick out all "single-N" words in a string (not sure if that's what you actually need, but the array of strings you have in the example suggests that might be the case).

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    internal class Program {
        private static void Main(string[] args) {
            var pattern = new Regex(@"\bN\b");
            const string input = "N foo N bar N";
            MatchCollection matches = pattern.Matches(input);
            Debug.Assert(matches.Count == 3);
            foreach (Match m in matches) {
                Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need the character class (`[` and `]`) when it's only one character `^N$` means the same as `^[N]$`.

What your regex is matching is a string that consists of a single character: `N`.

`^` matches the start of a string and `$` the end of it the only valid character in between is `N`, so it will **only** match the string `N`.

**Update:**

If all you're after is a string consisting of `N`, then you don't need regex at all, as other have suggested, use `if (word == "N")` or if you want to get any words consisting of `N` out of a larger string then you'd use `\bN\b`.

Comment: what about `\bN\b`? Yours just matches any N that isn't surrounded by Ns - I believe the question asks for Ns 'on their own'.  Granted that's a little bit ambiguous, since that could mean the whole string is 'N', or that any Ns surrounded by whitespace are required.

Comment: I just realized that that's what he's after, as the words are in an array it seemed absurd to want a regex for matching `N` as the regex would be `N`. If picking out words **in a string** that are `N` then `\bN\b` would do the job.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just trying to find an exact match to the string `"N"` then there's no need to use a regex!

```
if ( word == "N" ) ...
```

Comment: Alternate LINQ syntax: foreach (string word in words.Where(word => word == "N")) { ... }